# if QString contains a number

Tags: c++, string, qt, qstring

I want to know if a string contains a '1' or '0' so I wrote this code:

```
    if ((input.contains('0'))||(input.contains('1'))) {
        ui->answerbox->setText(QString::number(BinToDec(number)));
    }
    else {
        ui->answerbox->setText("Error");
    }
```

If I put in "014", it runs the if block but if I put "4" it runs the else block. What's wrong?

Comment: Nothing is wrong.The second string does not contain a `1` or a `0`, so it runs the else block. What were you expecting the code to do?

Comment: What's the problem? "4" doesn't contain a 0 or a 1.

Comment: Title says about numbers, but you check against '1' and '0' only. What exactly do you need?

Comment: Are you mixing up the character '1' and '0' with binary representation of numbers? They are not the same.

Comment: If input is "4" the application must run the else block, as it does not contain 0 nor 1

Comment: Oh I'm stupid. I expected it to run the if block if the string contains ONLY 1's or 0's and else block if it contains anything else than 1 or 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man this function `BinToDec` is a total disaster.

```
bool success;
auto value = input.toInt(&success, 2);
if (success) {
    ui->answerbox->setText(QString::number(value));
}
else {
    ui->answerbox->setText("Error");
}
```